# How to set Jira default groups for new users?

Tags: security, jira

I'm using Jira on demand and I'm trying to change the default groups a new registered user belongs to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the chosen groups to the **Jira Users** global permission. Any newly created users will automatically go into these groups.

Note that the sum total of distinct users in these groups will be your licensed user count. (Although I'm not sure if this works the same way with Hosted Jira)